# How to change ionic gesture reference element dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to build a tinder like swipe ui.
So when a Card is swiped, I need to set the gesture onto the next card to have another swipe effect, currently the whole swiping works, but only for the first card.

So basically I need to change the ElementRef of a gesture object dynamically (IMO the el inside of the created gesture).

```
@ViewChildren('tinderCards', { read: ElementRef }) tinderCards!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
...
async ngAfterViewInit() {
...
const gesture = await this.gestureCtrl.create({
      el: this.tinderCards.first.nativeElement,
      gestureName: 'tinder-swipe',
      ...
});

gesture.enable();

}
```

My problem is now:

- How is the most performant way to set a gesture onto multiple Elements? Is there another way to set this gesture instead of inside of ngAfterViewInit onto every element?
- What if new elements are loaded when swiping through? They won't be accessible in ngAfterViewInit but the gesture needs to be set..

Thank you in advance, please be kind, I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the life cycle hook of Angular. The `ngAfterViewInit()` is `Called once after the first`, so you may use detect changes to have the effect that you want.
Please, take a look into Angular [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).